# Vogels : ValidationException : The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, vogels

I am using vogels library in my project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vogels).

Below is the schema

```
test2-help-opens:
 hashKey: time
 timestamps: true

 schema:
   time: string
   channel: string    
   status: number
```

Here time column is the hash key. Below is the code where i am fetching data from DynamoDB using channel key

```
getOpenRequestModel().get({ channel : 'yes' };, (fetchErr, resp) => {
    if(fetchErr){
        console.log('Something went wrong to fetch',fetchErr);
        response = { status:false, statusCode: 200, body: 'Something went wrong while fetching from open request' };
        cb(null, response);
    }else{
        console.log('Response from findOpenRequest',resp);
        response = { status:true, statusCode: 200, body: resp };
        cb(null, response);
    }
});
```

I am facing an Validation Error **{ ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema**

I have tried many things but didn't find any solution can someone please help me in this it will be really helpful.